# Angular 2 : Creating object in interface

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying to create nested object as below

```
myForm value: 
{
  "name": {
         "firstname":"abc",
         "lastname":"xyz"
   },
  "address": {
    "street": "assdasdasdsa",
    "postcode": "8000"
  }
}
```

In interface, there is option to specify string,number, array types syntax

I tried below options but no luck and it is throwing error "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name:" (workarounds from SO and others didn't help)

```
export interface Customer {
    name: {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
};
    addresses: Address[];
}

export interface Address {
    street: string;
    postcode: string;
}
```

Could you please provide me options to specify object as mentioned above?

Plunker- https://embed.plnkr.co/hQ6RtzCfPosfQl4HlbZQ/

In Angular 1, it was easy with scope object and using ng-model as "myForm.name.firstname"

Codepen tried in angular1 - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mmYgbr and trying to replicate same in angular 2

Comment: Plunker is working fine?

Comment: yes ,Plunker url is working fine with name as string and I am trying to change it as object which is not working

Comment: well make a new interface for `Name`: `export interface Name {firstname: string; lastname:string}` address: `export interface Address {street: string;postcode: string;}` and customer: `export interface Customer{name: Name;addresses:Address[]}`

Comment: app.component.html:7 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'firstname' , getting same error after trying with above option

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/0DUzMNZ9VBwEJrASVuyR?p=preview

Comment: You need to wrap your name form controls inside with your formgroupname :)  `<div formGroupName="name">.......</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a form group `name` in your TS, which contains the form controls `firstname` and `lastname`. You had forgotten to apply that in your template. So you need to wrap the form controls with `formGroupName`:

```html
<div formGroupName="name"> <!-- Here -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastname">
 </div>
```

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z06fUl82zURf89V9bQAg?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks AJT, it  works great.... :)  not sure about downvote :) for this question :(

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! Well you got an upvote from me ;P Have a nice day/evening/night and happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot AJT  :)